# No response with jquery-mockjax

Tags: jquery, mockjax

I am trying to use jquery-mockjax library to mock ajax, but I cannot see any response.
My code is as follow :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="components/jquery-mockjax/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $.mockjax({
                url: '/test/inline',
                contentType: "text/json",
                responseTime: 0,
                responseText: {
                    say: 'Hello world!'
                }
            });

            $('#btn').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/test/inline',
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(json) {
                        alert('You said: ' + json.say);
                    },
                    complete: function() { 
                        $.mockjaxClear(); 
                        alert('completed');
                    }
                });
            }
            );
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn">Get</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: I found the reason. I used jquery version >2.0

Comment: After downgrading jquery version to 1.9.1, it works!

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer, not as a comment.  Also, which version of mockjax are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem and was banging my head for half an hour, and shouting "why?"

Try downgrading jQuery to 1.*

Answer (score 0):

ResponseTime increase.

```
responseTime: 10,
```